Can't get my head around how random effects affect interpretation of model coefficients
For example, if you are interested in the effect of age on another variable, and you have 3 repeats per individual, but individuals vary in age from the start, is the estimate for age in a random effects model telling you about change within individuals, variation across individuals, or both?

Consider a model with a fixed effect of age and a random intercept across individuals as in
$y_{ij}=b_{0j}+b_1age_{ij}$
where $i$ indicates the occasion number, 1, 2 or 3, and $j$ the person. Then $b_1$ tells you about the effect of age within a given person as well as between different people, so it is a combination of both types of influence of age. If you like to know the effect of age within a person and between people separately, you could first subtract the mean age of the three ages from each age and use:
$y_{ij}=b_{0j}+b_1(age_{ij}-\overline{age}_j)+b_2\overline{age}_j$
In the above model $b_1$ gives the within person effect and $b_2$ the between effect. The combined effect of the previous model lies in between $b_1$ and $b_2$ of the latter model.

Both. The age coefficient in a random effects (that is, random intercept) model is a weighted average of  the coefficients in purely between-individual and purely and within-individual  (i.e. individual fixed effects) models, with the weights depending on the relative size of the standard errors of the coefficients in each model. In brief, the coefficient from the random effects model with approach the one from the fixed effects model when the within subject standard errors are much smaller than the between-subjects standard error. When the between-subjects standard errors are much larger than the within-subject standard errors, the random effects model coefficient approaches the one from the between effects model.
